# How to convert tensor from 2D to 4D

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm currently working with DICOM files and the TensorFlow IO library for DICOM files seems to throw some errors. So what I was originally doing was this:

```
    # read file bytes
    image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(image_path)

    # Convert to a tensor
    image_as_tensor = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_bytes, dtype=IMAGE_TYPE)

    print(image_as_tensor.get_shape())
```

```
(1, 519, 519, 1)
```

Anyways, I instead decided to load the DICOM files with `pydicom`, which seems to work loading the data into a `numpy` array. Yet, when I [create a tensor from the data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor), I can't seem to get it in the correct dimensions:

```
        # read into dicom file
        ds = pydicom.dcmread(image_path)
        print(ds.pixel_array.shape)

        # take pixel array, and lets create a tensor
        image_as_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(ds.pixel_array, dtype=IMAGE_TYPE)
        print(image_as_tensor.get_shape())
```

```
(519, 519)
```

Ultimately, I do want the (Z, X, Y, D) format for some later parts of the program, but not sure how to get the 2D tensor into that version.

Thanks!

Comment: X.reshape(1, x_shape, y_shape, 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [`numpy.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((20, 30))
shape = arr.shape

print(shape)
# (20, 30)

arr = arr.reshape(1, *shape, 1)
print(arr.shape)
# (1, 20, 30, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand_dims` from `numpy`

```
X = np.zeros((519, 519))
X.shape # (519, 519)
X_ = np.expand_dims(X, [0, 3])
X_.shape # (1, 519, 519, 1)
```